# time.time not returning current epoch time?

Tags: javascript, python

In python `time.time()` returns the time in seconds since the epoch as a floating point number, but it seems the number is a bit short. If I run in JavaScript `new Date().valueOf()` I get 13 digits in length.

But if I run python `time.time()` I get a float with 10 digits and 6 after the decimal. Is `time.time()` not the correct method to use to get the same 13 digits as JavaScripts `new Date().valueOf()` method which says:

> The `valueOf()` method returns the primitive value of a Date object as a number data type, the number of milliseconds since midnight 01 January, 1970 UTC.

Comment: It's not that hard to convert between seconds and milliseconds, isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "correct" value of the number of seconds elapsed since 1/1/70 is the 10 digit number returned by Python.

> `new Date().valueOf()`

Returns the value in milliseconds. If you want to get the number of seconds elapsed since 1/1/70, you need:
`new Date().valueOf() / 1000;`

```
new Date().valueOf() / 1000
# 1641855239.355

Math.round(new Date().valueOf() / 1000);
# 1641855239
```

> time.time()

Python returns the number of seconds elapsed since 1/1/70 and adds precision after the decimal point.

```
>>> import time
>>> time.time()
1641855239.3550372
>>> 
>>> round(time.time())
1641855239
```